# Trouble setting custom header in Apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm using Apollo Graphql in a ReactJS project, it's using 'Json Web Tokens' which is required at every query or mutation to authenticate.

The problem i'm facing is that instead of Authorization being added as an Key:Value pair, it's being added to the Access-Control-Request-Headers which my backend(Java/Spring Boot) can´t find.
When i do the call from my React project i get a 500 response back, but when using Postman i get '200 OK'

Any recommendations on how i can manage my Post Method to do the call correctly?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AppRouter from './AppRouter';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});
console.log(authLink)
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin' 
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  ssrMode: true,
  connectToDevTools: true,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink)
});


function App() { 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <AppRouter/>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is what the headers looks like

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/Runners
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```

And this is how they should look like

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Authorization: Bearer ...............
Referer: http://localhost:3000/Runners
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
```